# ionic3 Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: ionic3

I am using the Ionic Cordova build Android --prod and I get this error:

[image: Error message]

Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v10.8.0
    npm               : 6.3.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @ionic/app-scripts 3.1.1. That was a bug on 3.1.0.
You can see it [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1309#issuecomment-344036711)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```